# Alcun+altra va con l'apostrofo?

Tags: writing

Domanda banale, stimolata dalla sottolineatura rossa che vedo sotto *alcun'altra* che mi suggerisce di cambiare a favore di *alcun altra*.

Se non ricordo male il motivo per cui si scrive *un'altra* e non *un altra* è che *un* è articolo maschile, che non viene usato con *altra*, si usa invece *una* che perde la vocale finale e guadagna l'apostrofo.

Ora assumerei che anche *alcun* è maschile, per cui lo stesso ragionamento si applicherebbe, il che vorrebbe dire che scriverei *alcun altro* e *alcun'altra*.

Ma le cose stanno così?

---

Unrelated/meta- and to be deleted, how is it possible that there's no [apostrophe](/questions/tagged/apostrophe) tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Credo proprio che la scrittura giusta sia con l'apostrofo. Ad esempio così dice il vocabolario Treccani:

> si scrive perciò un uomo, un angolo, nessun altro, alcun amico, buon
> appetito (e non un’uomo, un’angolo, ecc.), nello stesso modo che un
> soldato, nessun danno, alcun libro, buon viaggio (invece nel femm.
> un’isola, nessun’altra, alcun’amica, buon’anima, con l’apostrofo); tal
> altro e femm. tal altra, qual è, qual orrore e femm. qual idea (cfr.
> in tal caso, la tal via, qual dolore, qual vista);  <sup>1</sup>

E' per caso il Word che sottolinea in rosso? Non badare troppo al Word, se non come indicazione per controllare, perché spesso sbaglia.

L'equivoco credo venga dalla solita questione di distinguere tra *troncamento* e

*apocope vocalica*, come nel caso di *qual è* (ma nel tuo caso mi sembra chiaro che è un troncamento):

https://accademiadellacrusca.it/it/consulenza/lesatta-grafia-di-qual-%C3%A8/6

Per inciso, trovo sempre le opinioni dell'Accademia della Crusca le più illuminanti, perché hanno una visione poco rigida e più storica della grammatica, tanto che avanza l'idea che probabilmente sarà in futuro accettato anche *qual'è* con l'apostrofo, visto che è diventato frequente nell'uso.

Ma non mi pare che ci sia un uso di *alcun altra* senza apostrofo che ne giustifichi l'adozione.

---

<sup>1</sup> https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/apostrofo/

Comment: No, non è Word, ma il motore di spelling dell'[editor di cui faccio uso](https://www.vim.org/).

Comment: @Enlico: Visto che vim è open source, c'è modo di sapere come è stato fatto il suo correttore ortografico? Se usando un corpus di testi italiani, regole scritte esplicitamente o altro?

Comment: Mi dispiace, non ne ho idea, ho esperienza con Word, che tra l'altro non mi piace, ma ho l'impressione che non è tanto che sbaglia la grammatica,  ma spesso mette sotto segni rossi a cavolo, non si capisce perché, poi caso mai la volta dopo alla stessa parola non mette segni rossi.

Comment: Chiedo scusa, credevo che la domanda fosse stata fatta a me.

Comment: @Enlico Dipende da quale dizionario dai in pasto a vim nella configurazione. Evidentemente ne stai usando uno di incompleto che non contiene tutte le forme con l'apostrofo.

Comment: @DenisNardin, sì, sicuramente sarà così. Devo cercare di capire da dove prendere un dizionario completo o, se non altro, meno incompleto.